# How to read content of the address bar after '?' sign and insert value to HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I am redirecting from some page to index.html. Page redirect to index by using following address in the address bar: `http://localhost/index.html?page.html`

How can I read the value after `?` sign and insert it (page.html) into index.html file?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
var url = window.location.href;
var params = url.split('?');

alert(params[1]);
```

Comment: If I insert this then I am being displayed a message box with message "undefinded".

Comment: it works. make sure you actually have something after `?`. http://jsfiddle.net/vWw9m/

Comment: yup, i know. just doing things differently.

Answer (score 6):

[`window.location.search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location#Location_object) along with [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) to remove the `?`

More information can be found through the link regarding the property, but with regards to printing it on the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var GET = window.location.search.substring(1);
  document.write(GET);
</script>
```

Comment: It doesn't display the path if I insert this into html page.

Comment: @HelpNeeder: I guess I'm not 100% sure I understand what you mean by _insert_ then. I assumed write it out, but what is your intent?

Comment: If I paste this code to index.html alone then I'm not getting any text on screen.

Comment: @HelpNeeder: You'd need to visit `.../index.html?inhex.html` (or a question mark with any text following it)

Comment: Ok, I got something to work here with Joseph answer, but it doesn't work if I try to use this as a link. Look at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tBjZH/)

Comment: @HelpNeeder: The code I've provided won't work in fiddle because the "execute" iframe will never have a "get" variable on it, so the `search` property will always come up short. However, on your example (note the red text) you can't escape the final quotation mark and not still have another one to wrap the contents of the write in. You'd need `document.write("<a href=\"");` or, better yet, `document.write('<a href="');` -- p.s. Here's your code corrected: http://jsfiddle.net/tBjZH/1/

Answer (score 3):

`Split()` the `document.URL` by the `lastIndexOf` and parse it from there:

```
var url=document.URL;
var urls=url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('?')+1,url.length);
console.log(urls);
// urls will contain everything right of the ?
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also extract it with a RegExp. Maybe not ideal but a solution nonetheless:

```
var url = location.href.match(/\?(.+)/)[1];
```

Comment: [Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html) (More for humor than insult; but you are absolutely correct, you can use regex.)

Comment: lol, yeah, I read that before...But if it works and it's transparent to you why not?

Comment: I have a rule of thumb: If the environment comes with a solution to the problem I take the environment's approach 110% of the time.

Comment: I am getting Message: 'location.href.match(...).1' is null or not an object

Comment: It should work. Make sure you're escaping `?` and grabbing the capturing group with `[1]`. http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/C77qf/